# Web application development security best practices

Tags: security, secure-coding

I am looking for the current, state of the art, coding standards for web development (mostly PHP). Since I do not want to reinvent the wheel I would like to reuse libraries written by people much clever than I am.

I know about OWASP which is a wonderful source of best practices and brilliant information. Their web site is however quite unorganized when it comes to libraries.

- On the one hand there is OWASP ESAPI with pointers to libraries.
- On the other hand there is OWASP AntiSamy, which also has libraries. It in turn points to HTMLPurifier or the MS Anti-XSS library.

I did not find any links between these different solutions.

Is there currently a consensus on the most recommendable libraries to use in order to mitigate the major security risks?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add static code analysis to your testing. Many Cross-site scripting (XSS) problems are very difficult for the human eye to pick out. Automated code analysis finds them easily.

Answer (score 2):

(Hey, I know that Bruce Ediger character! ;)
Seriously, you did not mention what exactly you were looking for, but ESAPI is not a "coding style", but rather a library of various security controls. There is an '[ESAPI for PHP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=PHP)'. OTOH, AntiSamy only exists for Java and .NET, so if you are looking for something to help defend against XSS in PHP, ESAPI should get the nod.

However, Bruce is correct...to a degree. Unless you are doing a green-field approach on some brand new project, static or dynamic analysis is a definite plus, especially if you are working on a large code base. These tools will have you identify places within your code where you need to insert the ESAPI's security controls.

Finally, you might find this book useful (note: I have not read it at all, but based on its title and TOC, it would seem to fit the bill):
[Pro PHP Security: From Application Security Principles to the Implementation of XSS Defenses, Second Edition by Chris Snyder, Thomas Myer and Michael Southwell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430233184). It's published by Apress. I'll let you look it up on your favorite online bookstore, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I should have been more clear with my question. 
What I actually meant is that there are several libraries which get a recommendation from OWASP and they are not mentionned as "you can use ESAPI or AntiSamy" but rather get independednt sections without any cross links or comments.

Anyway I will have both tested to see which one will be easiest to implement in a PHP environment (since both cover PHP).